# Update post meta does not serialize array

Tags: array, wp-insert-post, post-meta

For some reason my `update_post_meta()` function does not accept an array. Normally the function serializes the array by itself, but now I need to do this by myself, otherwise it does not update.

Could this be, because I call it inside a Class?

**My code:**

```
class Checkout {

    // Initializes object, calls the init hook
    public function __construct( $testMode = false ) {

        // Calls the init hook
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'setup' ) );

    }

    public function setup() {

        // Insert a post 
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( array( 'post_title' => 'Post title', 'post_content' => '', 'post_type' => 'transaction', 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );

        // Create order data array
        $order_data = array( 
            'subtotal'  => 100,
            'vat'       => get_option( 'vat_percentage' )
        );

        // Update order price
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'order_data', $order_data );

    }

}

// Call object
$checkout = new Checkout();
```

Comment: What is the update_post_meta returning? Also, what does the data look like in the database?

Comment: @Tom Nothing, it is not storing the data..

Comment: He asked what it ***`returned`***, not what it did.

Comment: I mean if you assign a variable to the update_post_meta function what does it return? Like this: `$returnData = update_post_meta( $post_id, 'order_data', $order_data ); print_r($returnData);`

Comment: @Tom It returns the meta ID. So it looks like it is stored without value..

Comment: Are you able to print the value of $order_data to prove that, in the context the class is called, that it is valid? Instead of attempting the update_post_meta try just printing the values.

Comment: @Tom Yes I have done this before, and this is valid. That's also the reason that I can update the $order_data by serializing it by myself.

Comment: @Robbert at this point I have to assume it is something in the environment. Is there a way you can try updating the post meta outside your class?

Comment: It was indeed something in the environment. Still thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my way of including some classes with the [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function. This leaded into some problems inside the WordPress core. Excuse me for not testing this before.